# Boundary of Closure is Boundary

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

In several forums, it has been shown that $bd(\overline{S})$ is a subset of $bd(S)$; however, does the possibility of equality can occur for this case, meaning does the equality $bd(\overline{S}) = bd(S)$ hold for every set $S$ in $R^{n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boundary of the set of all rational numbers is the whole real life. Boundary of it's closure is empty.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why the boundary of the closure of $Q$ is considered empty?

Comment: Definition of the boundary $\partial{X}=\overline{X}-\mathring{X}$. In the case of $\Bbb{Q}$ one has $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}=\Bbb{R}$ and $\mathring{\Bbb{Q}}=\emptyset$. Whilst one has $\overline{\Bbb{R}}=\mathring{\Bbb{R}}=\Bbb{R}$